# UIView Category - custom method not returning a UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, categories

I created a Category on UIView with a method who's purpose it to create and return a UIView object. It runs without errors but returns an empty UIView. Here's the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (makeTableHeader)


 -(UIView *) makeTableHeader:(NSString *)ImageName
                  withTitle:(NSString *)headerTitle
                  usingFont:(NSString *)fontName 
                andFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize;


@end
```

Here's the Implementation:

```
-(UIView *) makeTableHeader: (NSString *)ImageName 
              withTitle:(NSString *)headerTitle 
              usingFont:(NSString *)fontName 
            andFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {

     // Create a master-view:
     UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 34)];

     // Create the Image:
     UIImageView *headerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:ImageName]];
     headerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 34);


     // Now create the Header LABEL:
     UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 320, 34)];
     headerLabel.text = headerTitle;
     headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
     headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);

     // Finally add both both Header and Label as subview to the main Header-view:
     [headerView addSubview:headerImageView];
     [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

     return headerView;
}
```

Now here's how I call this category-method:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *hView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [hView makeTableHeader:@"redGradientHeader5@2x.jpg"
                 withTitle:@"Test Banner"
                 usingFont:@"boldSystemFont"
               andFontSize:18];

    return hView;
```

}

The code runs fine - but I get an empty view. Interestingly it does *size* the view correctly - giving it the CGRect coordinates I asked for - but there's no image or label inside the view.

Anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the method a `class` method, and assign it like this:

```
UIView *hView = [UIView makeTableHeader:@"redGradientHeader5@2x.jpg"
             withTitle:@"Test Banner"
             usingFont:@"boldSystemFont"
           andFontSize:18];
```

You are making two views - one with alloc/init, and one with your custom function. However, you are only ever assigning the *first* one to `hView`. This is because in the `makeTableHeader` method, you are using `hView` to **create** a *second* UIView, and applying the subviews/modifications to *that* rather than modifying `hView`. This view is then returned by the method, and then immediately discarded because it is not assigned to anything.

Alternatively, if you insist on *keeping* it an instance method and *modifying* the view, you'll just have to do it like this (although I **strongly** do not suggest it):

```
-(void) makeTableHeader: (NSString *)ImageName 
              withTitle:(NSString *)headerTitle 
              usingFont:(NSString *)fontName 
            andFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
     //you may want to remove all subviews here or something
     // Create the Image:
     self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 34);
     UIImageView *headerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:ImageName]];
     headerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 34);


     // Now create the Header LABEL:
     UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 320, 34)];
     headerLabel.text = headerTitle;
     headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
     headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);

     // Finally add both both Header and Label as subview to the main Header-view:
     [self addSubview:headerImageView];
     [self addSubview:headerLabel];

}
```

Comment: this WORKS :-) (And I marked as correct answer) But I'm wondering: why are you so strongly against making it an Instance Method? Is it a general rule of thumb that if your method's purpose is to **create** and return an object you go with a Class method? Cause I've seen plenty of **instance** methods that create and return objects. Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: `Factory` methods (methods that are used for creating instances) should always be class methods because then you avoid the overhead of having to create an instance just to create the *second* instance which is the one you wanted. **The exception to this** is if you want the new instance to be partially based off of the old one.